# Getting first item in Julia SortedSet

Tags: julia

Is there any way of directly accessing the first element in a SortedSet? I'm currently iterating over the SortedSet and immediately calling `break`, but this seems inelegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`first`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.first). `first` gives you the first element of an iterable collection.

```
a = SortedSet([3,5,2,4,1])
first(a)
# or you can use piping syntax
a |> first
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I would have sworn that I tried `first', but obviously I didn't.